# Why is this DAG skipping a task even when the branch operator returns its task ID?

Tags: python, airflow, etl, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have the following DAG in Airflow:

```
    validate_and_prepare_config >> skip_detect_task >> [ingest, detect]
    detect >> export
    ingest >> skip_decrypt_task >> [decrypt, parse]
    decrypt >> parse >> vault_transfer >> skip_export_task >> [export, get_pipeline_state]
    export >> get_pipeline_state >> post_process
```

which looks like this visually in the Airflow UI:
[image: Visual representation of above DAG]

The desired behavior is to branch from `vault-transfer` to either

1.`export`, then `get_pipeline_state`

or

2.directly to `get_pipeline_state`

the `skip_export` task contains a branch operator which returns either "`export`" or "`get_pipeline_state`". When it returns "`get_pipeline_state`", it branches to the `get_pipeline_state` task as expected. However, when it returns "`export`", the DAG still skips the `export` task and still branches to `get_pipeline_state`.

this is what I'm seeing in the logs for the `skip_export` task:

```
{python.py:177} INFO - Done. Returned value was: export
{python.py:211} INFO - Branch callable return export
{skipmixin.py:155} INFO - Following branch export
{skipmixin.py:211} INFO - Skipping tasks []
```

and these are the XCOM values I'm seeing for the `skip_export` task:

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| return_value | export |
| skipmixin_key | {'followed': ['get_pipeline_state', 'export']} |

Why is this happening and how can I get the `skip_export` task to behave as expected?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of default [trigger rule](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html#trigger-rules) setting of **all_success**, meaning that a task will get executed only if all its predecessors are successful.

Your case is exactly described here:

> *export* is downstream of *detect* and *skip_export*. The *export* task will show up as skipped because its trigger_rule is set to all_success by default, and the skip (on *detect*) caused by the branching operation cascades down to skip a task marked as all_success.

On export task add `trigger_rule=none_failed_min_one_success` to make it work.

Honestly I'm not sure about your `get_pipeline_state` task - in theory it should have the same issue, but from the picture seems working fine. You can double check cases with and without tweaked trigger rule just to be sure.